# ion-note inside of ion-list cuts off primary text

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using ionic 3. I am trying to do a list of events where the event name is on the left side and the event note (the start time) is on the right side of the item in an ion-note. Here is my code:

```html
  <ion-list *ngIf="events.length !== 0">
    <ion-item-group>
      <ion-item-divider>
        Upcoming events
      </ion-item-divider>
      <button ion-item *ngFor="let event of events" (click)="itemTapped($event, event)">
        {{event.name}}
        <ion-note item-right>{{event.start | date: 'HH:mm'}}</ion-note>
      </button>

    </ion-item-group>
  </ion-list>
```

If I do just that, the note gets displayed on the right properly, however the primary text (the event's name) gets chopped off with an ellipsis inserted in the end, even though it would fit just fine. Here's a picture:

[image: ionic cuts off the primary text]

I have checked the documentation on ionic's website, and I copied over the demo source from here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/demos/src/list/pages/page-one/page-one.html

Funny enough, it looks good in their showcase but pasted into my application it looks just as off as my example.

The question is: how do I make ionic not cut off the primary text in my list?

Thanks.

**UPDATE: **I have found the solution. I have added a css rule (min-width:75%) for ion-notes in an scss associated with a different page, but that somehow got applied to this page as well. Removing that CSS rule fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you're using **item-right** class, however in the documentation as well as the demo source page, it is **item-end**.

Please check the item placement attributes here:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/Item/

If that doesn't help, you can try overriding the padding-right attribute of item-content.

Comment: You are right, I have forgot to edit my initial post. The results are the same when using item-right and item-end. I will come back to you with the other approach you provided.

Comment: Like this: .item-content {
    padding-right: 10px !important;
}

Comment: I have found the solution, please see my edit to the question. I don't really understand how that rule got applied to this page however, but that is out of the scope of this question. Thanks for your answer regardless. :)